# How to transform javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have got an array:

```
var tab = [];

          tab.push({key: 1,value: usa});
          tab.push({key: 2,value: germany});
          tab.push({key: 1,value: india});
          tab.push({key: 1,value: russsia});
          tab.push({key: 2,value: poland});
          tab.push({key: 1,value: uk});
```

And what I'm trying to do is to transform above array to receive:

```
[{"1":"usa,india,russia,uk"},
{"2":"germany,poland"}]
```

I'd like to have unique values in key field, and aggregate values from value fields.

How to achive this?

Comment: `{"1","usa,india,russia,uk"}` is not a valid Js object. Did you mean `{"1":"usa,india,russia,uk"}`

Comment: @GokhanKurt - yes, my mistake

Answer (score 4):

```js
var tab = [];
tab.push({key: 1,value: 'usa'});
tab.push({key: 2,value: 'germany'});
tab.push({key: 1,value: 'india'});
tab.push({key: 1,value: 'russsia'});
tab.push({key: 2,value: 'poland'});
tab.push({key: 1,value: 'uk'});

var transformedObject = {};

tab.forEach(function (item) {
  transformedObject[item.key] = transformedObject[item.key] ? `${transformedObject[item.key]}, ${item.value}` : item.value;
});

console.log(transformedObject);

// Access the '2' property
console.log(transformedObject['2']);
```

Comment: If I good understand, this is an array in object?
How to get "2" from this array?
I'd like to pass key from transformedObject to another function.

Comment: It's a simple object, use `transformedObject['2']`. I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce`:

```js
const orig = [{ key: 1, value: 'usa' }, { key: 1, value: 'russia' }, { key: 2, value: 'uk' }];

const result = orig.reduce((red, el) => {
  if (red[el.key] !== undefined) {
    red[el.key] += `, ${el.value}`;
  } else {
    red[el.key] = el.value;
  }
  return red;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```